# How to remove a child node keeping his child in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm not so good in javascript.
I have a DOM structure like this:

```
<div data-embed-url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5DkrwfY2jw4">
 <div class="black">
  <div>
   <div style="left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 0px; position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.2493%;">
     <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5DkrwfY2jw4"></iframe>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

How can I remove the node with the class "black" and the div without style and class keeping the others?

Comment: Which of those `<div>` elements do you consider 'empty', they *all* have content so far as I can see. Incidentally, you've got a stray quote at the end of your `<iframe>` element's opening tag for some reason.

Comment: @DavidThomas sorry i modify the code. I need to remove the div without any style or class

Comment: No problem, it just helps avoid complications in your questions if your code doesn't have additional errors :) the elements you want to remove, then, are the `<div class="black">` and its child `<div>`?

Comment: Show what you want the final result to look like.

Comment: Can you use jQuery? It has a method `.unWrap()` that will remove a container element and leave the contents.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using ES5:

```
// Find the `.black`
var black = document.querySelector('.black');

// Replace `.black` with its first child
black.parentNode.replaceChild(black.firstChild, black);
```

Comment: Oh, this has nothing to do with ES5, it's pure javascript (as in host scripting). ;-)

Comment: @RobG `var` part has some things to do with ES5 actually. I haven't used `var` for a while, and I'm totally not a fan of that keyword, that's why I mentioned ES5 :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use ID's on your div's to manipulate the DOM. ID's are meant to be unique. Using classes is discouraged as you can use class on mulitiple DOM nodes.

```
// Removing a specified element when knowing its parent node
var d = document.getElementById("top");
var d_nested = document.getElementById("nested");
var throwawayNode = d.removeChild(d_nested);
```

More information: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild

An example using your code with div ID:

```js
// Removing a specified element when knowing its parent node
var d = document.getElementById("blackId");
var d_nested = document.getElementById("blackChildId");
var div_i_want = d_nested.innerHTML;
alert('BEFORE: ' + d.innerHTML);
var throwawayNode = d.removeChild(d_nested);
d.innerHTML = div_i_want;
alert('AFTER: ' + d.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div data-embed-url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5DkrwfY2jw4">
 <div class="black" id="blackId">
  <div id="blackChildId">
   <div style="left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 0px; position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.2493%;">
     <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5DkrwfY2jw4"></iframe>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to remove the two `div` elements, while keeping the nested content (in order to simplify the nesting), then you could use `.replaceChild()` like this:

```
var black = document.querySelector('div.black');
var divToKeep = black.children[0].children[0]; 
black.parentNode.replaceChild(divToKeep, black);
```